# working with elements of dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, moving-average

I have a dataset which is a dict which consisting of lists (number of elements in each list is fixed, but the dict itself has a large number of entries)

E.g.:

```
d1 = {0: [1,2,3], 
      1: [2,3,4], 
      2: [3,4,5], 
      3: [4,5,6], 
      4: [5,6,7] }
```

now i need to create a dict such that:

```
d_required = { 0: [d1[0][0]/1, d1[0][1]/1, d1[0][2]/1],
               1: [(d1[0][0] + d1[1][0])/2, (d1[0][1] + d1[1][1])/2, (d1[0][2] + d1[1][2])/2],
               2: [(d1[0][0] + d1[1][0] + d1[2][0])/3, (d1[0][1] + d1[1][1] + d1[2][1])/3, (d1[0][2] + d1[1][2] + d[2][2])/3],
               3: [(d1[0][0] + d1[1][0] + d1[2][0] +d1[3][0])/4, (d1[0][1] + d1[1][1] + d1[2][1] + d1[3][1])/4, (d1[0][2] + d1[1][2] + d[2][2] + d[3][2])/4], 
               4: [(d1[0][0] + d1[1][0] + d1[2][0] + d1[3][0] + d1[4][0])/5, (d1[0][1] + d1[1][1] + d1[2][1] + d1[3][1] + d1[4][1])/5, (d1[0][2] + d1[1][2] + d[2][2] + d[3][2] + d1[4][2])/5]}
```

i.e, the averaging window increases as I move down the dict.
I am unable to get my head around to code this and am seeking any form of help.

Here is my attempt (which doesnt seem like it is doing the right thing :( )

```
def weirdProcessing(dataDict):
    resultDict = {}

    for d in sorted(dataDict.keys()):
        l = dataDict[d]
        res = []
        for i in range(len(l)):
            tempSum = 0
            for k in range(d):
                tempSum += dataDict[k][i] 

            res.append(tempSum/float(d+1))
        if d == 0:
            resultDict[d] = copy.deepcopy(dataDict[d])
        else:
            resultDict[d] = res

    return resultDict
```

Comment: It appears likely you should use a list rather than dictionary for `d1` and `result`. I say that because your keys are whole numbers like the indices of list elements, and you desire to use them in an ordered fashion, with sorted() and with calculation on "earlier" elements.

Comment: Yes! I can, but there is also a possibility to have the keys as strings from the experiments which produce these results. So I stuck with dict,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = [0., 0., 0.]
resultDict = {}
for c, k in enumerate(sorted(d1)):
    s = [sum((x,y)) for x,y in zip(s, d1[k])]
    resultDict[k] = [x/(c+1) for x in s]
```

In the above:

- `s` is the cumulative sum
- `resultDict` is the new dictionary

For each key in `d1`, we update the cumulative sum `s` and add a new entry to `resultDict`.

This produces `resultDict`:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3],
 1: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
 2: [2, 3, 4],
 3: [2.5, 3.5, 4.5],
 4: [3, 4, 5]}
```

#### As a function

The above code, in the form of a function, looks like:

```
def cumave(d1):
    s = [0., 0., 0.]
    resultDict = {}
    for c, k in enumerate(sorted(d1)):
        s = [sum((x,y)) for x,y in zip(s, d1[k])]
        resultDict[k] = [x/(c+1) for x in s]
    return resultDict
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in one line.

`for k in range(d):`

The `range` is exclusive of the last value. Change it to `range(d+1)`.